# How can I have multiple combination restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial

If I have 7 different attributes `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` that need to be combined into as many unique groups of 4 as possible, but 6 and 1, 6 and 3, and 3 and 4 are incompatible with each other what should I do? No repeats and order doesn't matter.

`(K = 4, N = 7)` ${}^{7}C_{4}$

Incompatibilities: `(6 and 1), (6 and 3), (3 and 4)`

I know I can reverse engineer it by making 1 of my incompatible groups required instead of incompatible `(K = 4-2, N = 7-2) = (K = 2, N = 5)` ${}^{5}C_{2}$ then finding the difference between my full answer and incompatibles answer ${}^{7}C_{4}$ - ${}^{5}C_{2}$, but I don't know what to do if there are multiple incompatibilities.

Comment: Would recommend that you look at PIE (Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion): https://brilliant.org/wiki/principle-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-pie/

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to read about that, but I might need to.

Comment: haha id say that's a really basic tool if you're trying to learn some combinatorics, so its probably unavoidable... unfortunately these kinds of combinatorics problems can be a little messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an equation, but there's an easy way to do it manually.
Start with the numbers in order `1234`. Then you can change the last number to the next number up one `1235`, do this until you've done this with the rest of the numbers `1236` `1237`. Then change the second to last character to the next highest and repeat the last step. `1245` `1246` `1247`. Then you can continue moving down the line `1256` `1257`, `1345` `1346` `1347` `1356`... While making it or when you're done you can dismiss the incompatible ones. It feels like it shouldn't work, but I don't know.

Maybe there's something here for an equation, but I'm not smart enough to make one.

Answer (score 0):

I've mapped it out if anyone cares to analyse...

```
1234 (34)
1235
1236 (16)(36)
1237
1245

1246 (16)
1247
1256 (16)
1257
1267 (16)

1345 (34)
1346 (16)(34)(36)
1347 (34)
1356 (16)(36)
1357

1367 (16)(36)
1456 (16)
1457
1467 (16)
1567 (16)

2345 (34)
2346 (34)(36)
2347 (34)
2356 (36)
2357

2367 (36)
2456
2457
2467
2567

3456 (34)(36)
3457 (34)
3467 (34)(36)
3567 (36)
4567
```